# Why can't I hide a div by CSS "-webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);"?

Tags: css, transform, perspective, css-transforms

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>An HTML Document</title>
<style>
    #container {
        -webkit-perspective: 300px;
        -moz-perspective: 300px;
    }
    #contents {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background: red;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    }
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div id="contents"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Ss6m

I wanna hide `.contents` by CSS `transform: rotateY(90deg);`. But codes above doesn't work properly. If I remove CSS `perspective`, it works properly. But I need CSS `perspective`.

How can I successfully rotate `.contents` to true 90 degree in Axis Y when I also set CSS `perspective` in `.container`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your perspective origin is wrong (i.e. it is off-axis with regard to your `rotateY()`). Adding `-webkit-perspective-origin-x: 150px` seems to do the trick: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ss6m/1/).

Comment: btw the reason this works is that it moves the perspective "camera" to the middle of your div (300px/2), which is the default rotation point for transforms if there's no transform-origin specified.